# Terraform: automate state mv (migration / evolution)

Tags: terraform

I'm currently facing problems refactoring terraform scripts, e.g. 
a root module refers to several other modules, which are refactored into a new module called main. In this case I ended up calling

```
terraform state mv module.XXXX  module.main.module.XXX
```

for every module `XXXX`.

That's fine for me.

In my case the root module is used by several workspaces, so I end up repeating this step for every workspace. I wonder if there's some kind of automation for terraform state evolution, like flyway on a smaller scale.