# Is there a way to perform resource renaming (terraform state mv) as a part of schema migration?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

This question is very similar to [Terraform: automate state mv (migration / evolution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027862/terraform-automate-state-mv-migration-evolution)

Is it possible to do a resource rename `foo` -> `fooo` by implementing `StateUpgraders` [attribute](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/4681738a561387fb0b3aaa69aeb42231383634a0/helper/schema/resource.go#L107), i.e. programmatically change TF state instead of manually running `terraform mv foo.example fooo.example`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in newer versions of Terraform you should be able to use the `moved` keyword [1]. An example from the docs:

```
resource "aws_instance" "a" {
  count = 2

  # (resource-type-specific configuration)
}


resource "aws_instance" "b" {
  count = 2

  # (resource-type-specific configuration)
}

moved {
  from = aws_instance.a
  to   = aws_instance.b
}
```

Since you did not give any more details (e.g., which provider and/or resource type) the example above will work only for the `aws` provider and for the `aws_instance` resource, but you can do the same for any other provider and resource type.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax

Comment: that looks like a permanent HCL change, is there something similar to StateUpgraders that won't require HCL changes besides resource name update?

Comment: I would strongly advise against any kind of terraform state file manipulation, but if that works for you, that's a valid option as well.